# Why i cannot directly call the php file inside folders using the directory path?

Tags: php, url, directory

I have one root folder called GASS where I put all my php files and other related folders (templates,images,js,fonts,css)inside. When i try to run my project in localhost, `http://localhost/GASS/alarm_A16GSM.php` everything went smoothly.
I wanted to change the URL to be more specific,
`http://localhost/GASS/alarmsystem/16zone/A16/overview.php`
thus i rename the php file and put it inside folders.

- GASS

  - alarm-system

    - 16-zone

      - A16

        - overview

However when i try to run the new URL,the page shows error.

Code for the first URL where the page load successfully.

```
 <div class="overview"><a href="alarm_A16GSM.php" id="overview-selected"><span>
```

Code for the new URL where the page shows error.

```
<a href="alarm-system/16-zone/A16/overview.php" id="overview-selected">
```

This is the error message:

```
Warning: include(templates/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .....
```

How am i going to load the page successfully using the new URL? How am i going to traverse four levels up to the root directory so that the page load successfully? Why i cannot directly call the php file using the(alarm-system/16-zone/A16/overview.php) path?

p/s: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to properly change the URL path that has folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417220/how-to-properly-change-the-url-path-that-has-folders)

Comment: You should use htaccess to change URL structure..

Comment: @Scorpion could you please show me how?

Comment: @niaizahra http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to update all the relative urls to fit the new url structure.

check your,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

and

```
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

try with `/css/style.css` instead `css/style.css` sometime it may fix the problem.

**update**

change your links too according to the new URL structure

```
<a href="alarm-system/16-zone/A16/overview.php" id="overview-selected">
```

Comment: Here is my code for the first URL.

 <div class="overview"><a href="alarm_A16GSM.php" id="overview-selected"><span>
when i changed it into

 `<div class="overview"><a href="overview.php" id="overview-selected"><span>`
the page shows error message. What can i do so that the URL will shows the path of my folders just like what i want. Please show baby steps to me. I am new to this.

Comment: @Bondye can youplease help me?

Comment: @niaizahra Either you use URL rewriting or update all the links, stylesheets and JavaScripts as explained above. I wonder whether you are capable of using URL rewriting.